# connecting to SQL Server 2008 using MVC 3 ASP.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am new to ASP.net's MVC 3 (using VB) and I am trying to create an application that would connect to an SQL 2008 server database.  I have gone through a tutorial (Microsoft ASP.net's Movie DB tutorial) but the tutorial uses SQL compact edition.  I am having a hard time connecting.  Am I correct in assuming that once I create a model, I should be able to just connect to SQL 2008 by changing the connection string in the Web.config file, found at the root of the application folder?  I deleted the sql ce database from the App_Data folder.  In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I created a new database.  I then added this to my Web.config file:

```
      <connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionName"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=DELERIUM-PC;Initial Catalog=iDjItDb;Integrated         Security=True" />
       </connectionStrings>
```

The when I run the app, and try to view the controller associated with the model, i get this error:

> The model backing the 'iDjItDBContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database,
>   or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance.
>   For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will
>   automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it
>   with new data.

What must I do to connect and work with a 2008 SQL database?

Thanks
jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `IncludeMetadataConvention` in your context class if you are positive that your model is compatible with the database.

```
public class iDjItDBContext : DBContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
    }
}
```

Otherwise you need to set the initializer in the `Application_Start()` method of your `Global.asax.cs` file.

```
Database.SetInitializer<iDjItDBContext>(
        new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<iDjItDBContext>());
```

Otherwise you can take the [Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/27/code-first-migrations-august-2011-ctp-released.aspx) option where an external tool will generate the change script.

**Edit**
Change the connection string name to `iDjItDBContext` so that the name matches with the `DbContext` name.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="iDjItDBContext"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=DELERIUM-PC;Initial Catalog=iDjItDb;Integrated         Security=True" />
       </connectionStrings>
```

Or create a constructor in your context and pass the name of the connection string.

```
public class iDjItDBContext : DBContext
{
     public iDjItDBContext() : base("ConnectionName")
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  While this removes all errors, I am confused as to where the data is being stored.  When I add new data to the application, i can see that it saves (even after restarting the server instance) but there is no data in the specified database on the SQL server, nor is there a database in the App_data folder.  Is it just being stored in memory?  thanks

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed it!

Comment: @Eranga I am following [this tutorial.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model%27s-data-from-a-controller) Although I have specified the full version of sql server connection string for my data source, I figured the programme has infact utilized the existing application services data source. I want to use my local data source to create the db and do crud via EF. Can you help me out here?